# How to use this most simple jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie question please bear with me. I am following this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them/). It illustrates how to write a very simple plugin. But may I ask how to use/call this plugin?

```
<script>
    function changeColor($obj, color) {  
        $obj.css({color : color});  
    }  

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {  

        return this.each(function() {  
            var $this = $(this);  

            changeColor($this, options.color);          
        });  
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know what [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is and how to load it and use it?  This code appears to provide a changeColor function for jQuery.

Comment: Yes, i do know jquery at basic level. Obviously I don't know how to write or use a plugin though.

Comment: So you found a tutorial that lets you write a piece of code and then doesn't tell you how to use it? Find another tutorial!

Comment: This is kinda contradiction. Use jQuery to access the "plugin" (which is just an extension to the jQuery Object)

Comment: Could anyone just answer the question? Show me the CODE about how to call the plugin.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I've added a full sample in my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KpUy/1/)

**HTML**

```html
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery already included)**

```js
function changeColor($obj, color) {
    $obj.css({
        color: color
    });
}

$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) { 
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        changeColor($this, options.color);
    });
};
$("div").myPlugin({
    color: "red"
});
```

---

Here is a full HTML code structure:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>Hello World!</div>

    <!-- Prepend http: in case you're working from the local file system -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function changeColor($obj, color) {
          $obj.css({
              color: color
          });
      }

      $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) { 
          return this.each(function () {
              var $this = $(this);

              changeColor($this, options.color);
          });
      };


      $("div").myPlugin({
          color: "red"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The API is a bit disappointing.... but it is what it is.  `$("div").color('red')` would be a lot nicer, but that's not this example.

Comment: @Paul I am not an expert with jQuery plugins, but what about http://jsfiddle.net/6KpUy/2/ ?

Comment: Thats a good one.  Could probably be collapsed into one function.  I suppose  it is unnecessary if you know about css().